# Speed of convergence of a Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let $f(x)=x^d$ $(d\in(-1,0))$. We know that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^d\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1x^d dx=\frac{1}{d+1}.$$
My question is the following: Can we say something about the speed of convergence? Something like
$$\left|\int_0^1x^d dx-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^d\right|\in O(n^d)?$$ I know that the last expression might be wrong. I just wanted to give you an idea what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There is a theorem that bound the difference between an integral and a sum by the product of the discrepancy of the arguments in the sum and the total variation of the function, but your function has infinite variation, so that's not going to help.

Comment: By using Euler-Maclaurin formula ( see Abramowitz & Stegun  ), we can see that convergence becomes better whenever $\large d$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us write $t_i = \frac{i}{n}$. Then, since $d < 0$, we have

$$\left\lvert\int_0^1 x^d\,dx - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}t_i^d \right\rvert = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} x^d - t_i^d\,dx.\tag{1}$$

Writing

$$x^d - t_i^d = -d\int_x^{t_i}\xi^{d-1}\,d\xi$$

and interchanging the order of integration, we obtain

$$\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} x^d - t_i^d\,dx = \lvert d\rvert \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} (\xi - t_{i-1})\xi^{d-1}\,d\xi. \tag{2}$$

For $i = 1$, the integral is easily computed as

$$\int_0^{1/n} x^d - \frac{1}{n^d}\,dx = \frac{1}{1+d}\left(\frac{1}{n^{d+1}} - 0\right) - \frac1n\cdot \frac1{n^d} = \frac{\lvert d\rvert}{(1+d)n^{d+1}},$$

so we have a lower bound of $\Omega(n^{-(1+d)})$ for the convergence.

For $i \geqslant 2$, we can bound the right hand side of $2$ above by replacing $\xi^{d-1}$ with $t_{i-1}^{d-1}$, and obtain an upper bound of

$$\frac{\lvert d\rvert}{(1+d)n^{d+1}} + \sum_{i=2}^n \lvert d\rvert t_{i-1}^{d-1}\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} (\xi - t_{i-1})\,d\xi = \frac{\lvert d\rvert}{(1+d)n^{d+1}} + \frac{\lvert d\rvert}{2n^{d+1}}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j^{d-1}.$$

The last sum converges (to $\zeta(1-d)$), so overall we have

$$\left\lvert\int_0^1 x^d\,dx - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}t_i^d \right\rvert \in \Theta(n^{-(1+d)}).$$

So for $d > -\frac12$, the convergence is even faster than $O(n^d)$, but for $d < -\frac12$ it is slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is really helpful.