# Prove the inequality for all $N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Show that the following inequality holds for all integers $N\geq 1$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{N}-c_1\right|\leq\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{N}}$$
where $c_1,c_2$ are some constants.

I have tried induction but it doesn't seem promising.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Idea: Divide by $\sqrt{N}$ and get $$\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n/N}} -2 - \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{N}}\right|$$ The sum is a Reimann sum for $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. Not sure how that helps...

Comment: [Related if not duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514492/speed-of-convergence-of-a-riemann-sum)

Comment: So can you give a complete answer for this question now? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $1/\sqrt{n}$ is decreasing, we can get an upper bound on the sum by computing: $$1+\int_1^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 1+2\sqrt{N}$$

Thus we have $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{N} = (1+2\sqrt{N}) - 2\sqrt{N} + E(N) = 1 + E(N)$$

Where $$E(N) = 1+\int_1^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > 0$$

is the error of our estimation at the point $N$. Now can you estimate $E(N)$?

---

Using the formula from Corollary 2.4 in the [pdf](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main2.pdf) linked in the comments, we find that $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \int_{1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx - \int_{1}^N \{x\} \frac{-1/2}{(x)^{3/2}}dx + 1$$

Here $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, which is always less than 1. The middle integral can be estimated by $$\left|\int_{1}^N \{x\} \frac{-1/2}{(x)^{3/2}}dx\right| < \int_1^N 1 \cdot \frac{1/2}{(x)^{3/2}}dx = 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$$

Comment: I don't actually know if you can estimate it. To be honest. Though there are some tricks that Euler came up with that might be helpful. Also try $c_1=1$ in this case.

Comment: It has already been estimated [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514492/speed-of-convergence-of-a-riemann-sum) ($d=-1/2$)

Comment: So it is. I believe we can obtain a more straightforward estimate using Corollary 2.4 from this: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main2.pdf

Comment: Hi @Joel. Can you please specify what values $c_1$ and $c_2$ are? Thanks.

Comment: Don't reference the comments in your answer. Just put the comment link in the answer. There might end up being many comments here, and the reader has to figure out which one you are referring to.